# C# Application accessing Server 2003 Web Service Authentication failed because the remote party as closed the transport stream

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, windows-server-2003

Recently Windows 11 performed an update (22h2 22621.819) that has broken the connection to a webservice (running on Windows server 2003 SP2) that has been working without issue.

When debugging this, I receive the below error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Boolean renegotiation)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)|   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
```

The application running on W10 (21H2 19044.2251) continues to work fine without any hiccups.

Can anyone provide me with some direction on what to do to allow the client access back to this service.
The server itself does not get anything from the client in these cases.

The event viewer logs on the client are showing "A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential.  The internal error state is 10013.  The SSPI client process is"
This is where I get a myriad of processes.. and PID..
WWAHOST
backgroundTaskHost
msteamsupdate
HxTsr

Can anyone provide me with some additional steps to try?

Thanks to all who read and provide feedback.

Regards PS

Have tried:
[https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/a-fatal-error-occurred-while-creating-a-tls-client/d7ffc963-ffab-4a34-97c8-7a321be6ed0c](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Not having any improvements on this issue..

Comment: What's your excuse for running a (presumably Internet-facing) web-service on an unsupported OS with numerous gaping security vulnerabilities?

Comment: $5 says it's to do with TLS changes that blocked older (and insecure) TLS protocols that your WS2003 box is presumably still using...

Comment: You should use a tool like Wireshark to analyze TLS handshake (though no doubt it shows Windows 11 is too new to continue on legacy protocol versions and ciphers).

Comment: LOL to both...I get it, would love to update the server, however it is company internal only.  And yes, I am sure that it has to do with the TLS since server 2003 doesn't support any of the modern secure protocols.  Just wondering how we can do a work around for the client blocking access to it.

Comment: Lex Li, I did test with Wireshark, not real sure what it even tells me since it does not appear to be letting it through, I will have to look at it further and add my testing results, maybe the community can offer more feedback after that.

Comment: _"I did test with Wireshark, not real sure what it even tells me since it does not appear to be letting it through"_ - what do you mean by "not letting it through"? Don't you see the TLS handshake messages?

Comment: _"Just wondering how we can do a work around for the client blocking access to it."_ - a pragmatic quick-fix would be to access the service over `http:` not `https:` until you can establish a better solution - it's on an Internal network after-all.